# Reduced schemes from schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

My homework problem is to prove that the embedding of the category of reduced schemes into the category of all schemes has a right adjoint. The most natural thing to do is to set $O'_x(U) : = O_x(U)/\sqrt{0}$ for any $U \subset (X, O_x)$. I can prove that this assignment is a presheaf but I can't prove that it is a sheaf.

Comment: You can show directly that $(X, O'_X)$ is a scheme, because you know that it works for affine schemes (and being reduced is a local property)

Comment: Actually I don't...